# Hat showing on top of snippet

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, winter-bash

When running the snippet in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164499/6632744), the user's hat didn't move with their profile image, and instead floated over top of the snippet.

[image]

Comment: That moving gif is just memorizing. I would look at it for hours :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357942/if-you-run-a-code-snippet-a-hat-still-appears-hats-are-above-snippets-in-the-z